# EditText freezes/doesn't show text whilst typing

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my `Android` application I have an `EditText` which is sat inside a `LinearLayout`. This page is used in a `ViewPager`.

On majority of the devices I have tested on, it seems that the `EditText` behaves perfectly fine, except on a few.

It appears that on a few devices, when I touch the `EditText` and start typing, the text doesn't show but the suggestions do show. It is only after the Keyboard is closed that the text appears within the `EditText`.

**Why is this the case? Why does the text not show whilst I type? Why does it show only after I close the keyboard?**

Code:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/searchGroup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

...
...

<EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textCapWords|textPostalAddress"
        android:id="@+id/searchText"
        android:hint="@string/locationHint"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:layout_below="@+id/locationGroup"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"/>

...
...
</LinearLayout>
```

**Update**
The `EditText` works fine if it's outside of the ViewPager`. It's only inside the ViewPager that it misbehaves.

Comment: Please try logging out the text in the EditText in `onTextChanged` and provide the result.

Comment: The `onTextChanged` and `afterTextChanged` are working perfectly fine.

Comment: See if you have the same problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21711237/edittext-in-android-doesnt-show-text-when-typing-while-using-the-on-screen-keyb)

Comment: @HuyTran I have seen that and it wasn't helpful. The OP made a silly mistake by locking the UI thread.

Comment: Try setting the text color to black.

Comment: Tried that. Doesn't work.

Comment: Hmm, what are the few devices that you mentioned?

Comment: Sony Xperia, Galaxy S3, Nexus 7...And probably more.

Comment: You said `onTextChanged` works perfectly fine. Does that mean the text you got using `getText()` is correctly updated every time you type in the EditText?

Comment: please provide more code..

Comment: hack: you can try setting from `onTextChanged` or `afterTextChanged`, since that works perfectly fine, it is just a hack even if it works.

Comment: @Subby I have seen this issue before. Are you using `myEditText.setText("")` to clear the EditText? If you are, replace that call with `TextKeyListener.clear(myEditText.getText())` or `myEditText.getText().clear()`. If that doesn't help, check if `Spell checker` is turned on in `Settings -> Language & input`. Try switching the `Spell checker` off and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: It works for me may b help full to others as well, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21711237/edittext-in-android-doesnt-show-text-when-typing-while-using-the-on-screen-keyb/41425153#41425153

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Having come across this issue at work with a number of devices and pulling my hair out (which I am sure you can appreciate) I found that wrapping the edittext view in a scrollview resolves the problem. The properties of the scrollview can be set so as not to affect the layout of your view.

Bounty me boy.

Comment: Wow that worked! Thanks a lot! Take my 500 points! You deserve it!

Comment: It works for me may b help full to others as well, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21711237/edittext-in-android-doesnt-show-text-when-typing-while-using-the-on-screen-keyb/41425153#41425153