# Text doesn't appear in EditText field while typing in Android 9

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-9.0-pie

I am developing a chat activity through Pubnub. While testing the chat page on Android Pie, the text doesn't appear in the EditText while typing. However, when I minimize the keyboard, the text that I typed earlier is visible.

How can I fix this problem? TIA.

Comment: This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21711237/edittext-in-android-doesnt-show-text-when-typing-while-using-the-on-screen-keyb

Comment: @Blacky_99 the link was for a diffeerent but I figured the solution after a while. An entry in the application tag of the Manifest file had to be added as given below - 

android:hardwareAccelerated="true"