# Android 10 EditText box not updating with keyboard inputs

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I've been thrown into trying to fix bugs in an app I didn't write, and I'm not all that familiar with Android. I'm having problems with text boxes not updating with keyboard inputs. Here's whats happening:
In android 10 (only) when I click on a text box, type stuff with the soft keyboard, nothing shows up in the textbox until the soft key board is minimized. But it works 100% fine in Android 5.1, 6, 8.1. (Also, compiling app with SDK for Android 8.1 or 10 makes no difference). The text box is never covered or hidden by the keyboard, it just remains empty until the keyboard is minimized.

The only thing that works is if I make the keyboard floating type, or if I position the textbox way at the top of the layout such that Android does not need to pan or resize the view to accommodate both the box and the default keyboard. A floating keyboard works anywhere, even partially over top of this text box.

I have tried every possible parameter combination I can find in the manifest and layout xml files, including android:windowSoftInputMode , android:fitsSystemWindows , android:isScrollContainer , android:gravity , android:paddingBottomandroid:configChanges

The fact this is -only- an issue for Android 10 is suspicious.

Comment: what have you tried? what isn’t working? please add code to your question

Comment: What are devices and keyboards? Do you use keyboard event listener?

Answer (score 3):

For anyone that finds this in the future: the issue turned out to be that hardware acceleration needed to be turned on. See [EditText in Android doesn't show text when typing while using the on-screen keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21711237/edittext-in-android-doesnt-show-text-when-typing-while-using-the-on-screen-keyb)

Comment: Great job pointing this out. This was the issue in my case. Big thumbs up :)